# Baseball - Reaching by Fielder's Choice

Tags: baseball

Nobody out. A Runner is on First Base. The next Batter hits the ball on the ground, and the Fielder gets the lead Runner out at Second Base, the Batter taking First Base. The same bases situation as before, except there is now one Out.

Do you see this as two Runners getting to First for the team, or just one? If that Batter had struck out, there would still be a Runner on First with one Out. How do you see this?

Comment: Are you asking in terms of how this would be officially scored in terms of whether the second batter is credited with a hit or something else? How you, I or anyone else that isn't the official scorer sees it is honestly not very important.

Answer (score 3):

The second batter is not credited with a hit and the pitcher is not charged with a hit. In fact, the second batter is charged with an at bat so it lowers their batting average. And the pitcher still gets credited with an out/ third of an inning pitched.

For the on base percentage statistic, the second batter is NOT credited with reaching base. So if that is what you are asking, I guess the answer is no.

> OBP refers to how frequently a batter reaches base per plate appearance. Times on base include hits, walks and hit-by-pitches, but do not include errors, **times reached on a fielder's choice** or a dropped third strike. (Bolding added)

https://www.mlb.com/glossary/standard-stats/on-base-percentage#

So from the standpoint of the second batter’s statistics it is same as any other out (not including sacrifices and outs that get RBI’s- it’s not even a productive non-sacrifice out) and from the pitcher’s statistics it is the same as any groundout.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're asking here. Perhaps you're just learning the game and I - and others looking at this so far - are familiar with it so communications are not great.

[Damila's answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/29096/13730) addressed the statistical issues, so I will not. Instead I'll attempt to provide some insight.

> Do you see this as two Runners getting to First for the team, or just one?

I see it as one runner at first being exchanged for another while an out has been made. The out is the most important issue here, as the offensive team is only allotted three per inning, so they've just used up one and not otherwise significantly affected their odds of scoring; however, at least they avoided a double play, so have two outs left and still have one runner on the basepaths. Also, a new batter is coming up who may be more or less effective as a hitter.

> If that Batter had struck out, there would still be a Runner on First with one Out.

Correct. The same is true if the batter had hit the ball in the air leading to an out without the runner advancing or the batter was called out for interfering with a defensive player's attempt to make a play.

> How do you see this?

Overall, I see it as a runner still being on first base, but now one more out made. In addition to what has already been said above, there may be subtleties involved such as exchanging a fast runner for a slow one or vice versa that could affect whether the runner on first base  will (eventually) score or not. If it's a game where pitchers bat (not currently applicable in Major and Minor League Baseball), maybe the pitcher will become a little more tired if he reached base - or get to rest a little if he was the runner who was out at second base.